# UILocalNotification - Repeat every 2 weeks

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uilocalnotification, repeat

How can I have a repat interval that repeats every 2 weeks?

[Pocket Lists](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pocket-lists/id482537116?ls=1&mt=8) uses `UILocalNotification`s and they have implemented it somehow.

Comment: Why not just schedule in batches?

Comment: @Paul.s Care to elaborate? :)

Comment: Schedule events for the foreseeable future and then if the user decides to change the frequency you can cancel them and schedule a new batch

Comment: @Paul.s ah you're basically agreeing on what user1567896 answered below?

Comment: Yup it would appear so, any reason why you don't like that solution? If not mark the answer as correct

Comment: @Paul.s just trying to get as much input as possible :) So for the repeat every 2 weeks scenario I would prolly need to schedule 3 notifications (to be covered 6 weeks if the user would not use my app for that time). Then if my calculations are correct that would leave me to be able to schedule a total of 21 (21*3=63) notifications of this type before hitting the maximum of 64 local notifications. This limit is a little troublesome. I'm wondering how Pocket Lists have taken care of that since that app is able to have 30+ notifications that repeats every 2 weeks.

Comment: If two events happen on the same day surely you can schedule them as one event and save on a scheduling, if as user hasn't opened your app in that period of time and you have been notifying them then they probably aren't that into your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not do it with repeatInterval.

What you can do is:

Handle the local Notification when it is pushed and simply add a new local Notification to be fired in two weeks.

Comment: But if the user doesn't open up the app before the 4th week the notification will not fire on the 4th week. So this solution depends that your user will open your application within 4 weeks.

Comment: For that you can add the Notifications a few times (covering a few months). When your app is started you can remove all notifications and add them again to be on the save side.